# How to schedule different works as a unique work?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

So I replaced all of my Jobs to these Work representation.

I have two problem in the current state of refactoring.

I have many worker classes, let's say these are W1,W2,W3...

My problem is, when I schedule a work as onTime and periodic as well. I use uniq works with uniq tags. My problem is, when I queue W1 as a periodic with "W1_TAG" tag and after that I would like to create a onTime from W1 with the same tag, it doesn't starts, because there is an another Work with the same tag.

I would like to achive that, If I start W1 worker, and after that start W2 worker as periodic, and after that I start W2 as onTime, the operation will be the following:

-W1 starts
-W2 periodic sees that, W1 runs, so he will wait untill w1 succeeded
-w2 onTime sees that, there is an another W2 (doesn't matter that it is periodic), and he will be removed? by WorkManager, so w2 periodic remains and w2 on time wont run

I know there is an enqueUniqWork possibility, but It only append, or keep the pervious worker, and this is not working different tags.

So currently I solved this, by add different tags, but I wondering, can I samehow resolve this?

**Work scheduling**

```
        fun schedulePeriodicAsync(context: Context) {
            val constraint =
                Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

            val data = Data.Builder()
            data.putBoolean(IS_PERIODIC_KEY, true)

            val sendCertificatesWorker =
                PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                    SendCertificatesWorker::class.java, 900000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS
                )
                    .setConstraints(constraint)
                    .setInputData(data.build())
                    .setBackoffCriteria(
                        BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                        OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                    ).build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                TAG,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, sendCertificatesWorker
            )
        }

        fun scheduleNowAsync(context: Context, workCallback: JobCallback? = null) {
            jobCallback = workCallback

            val constraint =
                Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

            val data = Data.Builder()
            data.putBoolean(IS_PERIODIC_KEY, false)

            val sendCertificatesWorker =
                OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SendCertificatesWorker::class.java)
                    .setConstraints(constraint)
                    .setInputData(data.build())
                    .setBackoffCriteria(
                        BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                        OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                    )
                    .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(
                TAG_NOW,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, sendCertificatesWorker
            )
        }

Worker class:
class SyncPricesWorker(
    val healthCheckApi: HealthCheckApi,
    val synchronizer: Synchronizer,
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
    private val context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Timber.d("SyncWorker starts")
        var workResult = Result.success()
        
        if (runAttemptCount >= 3) {
            return Result.failure()
        }

        workCallback?.jobStart()

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            Timber.d("SyncWorker middle")
            try {
                healthCheckApi.checkHealth(ApiModule.API_KEY).await()

                synchronizer.sendInvoices()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                workCallback?.jobEnd()

                workResult = Result.retry()
            }
        }

        if (workResult == Result.success()) {

            workCallback?.jobEnd()

            sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(ApiParameters.KEY_LATEST_PRODUCT_PRICE_SYNC_DATE, Date().time).apply()
        }

        Timber.d("SyncWorker end")
        return workResult
    }

Synchronization class method:
    suspend fun sendInvoices(invoiceHeaderIdToSend: String? = null): SendResult {
        val asd = invoiceRepository.getInvoicesWithStatus(0, invoiceHeaderIdToSend ?: "")
        if (asd.isEmpty()) return SendResult.success(10)

        val asd2 = salesApi.sendInvoices(asd).await()
        return if (asd2.isSuccessful) {
            val invoicesList = arrayListOf<InvoiceHeader>()
            invoicesList.addAll(asd)

            invoicesList.forEach { it.status = Constants.STATUS_SENT.code }

            invoiceRepository.updateInvoiceHeaders(invoicesList)
            SendResult.success(asd.size)
        } else {
            Timber.tag("sendInvoices").e(asd2.errorBody()?.string().toString())
            SendResult.error(asd.size, asd2.errorBody()?.string().toString())
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I would like to achive that, If I start W1 worker, and after that start W2 worker as periodic, and after that I start W2 as onTime` What do you mean here? Do you want to create 3 different work requests? Two OneTime and one periodic?

Comment: When the app has started in the main activity I create a periodic work request from W2 worker, but I also have a synchronization fragment, where the user can start an onTime work request from w2 worker. I would like to chain the different workers (w1,w2,w3), but in this case I have to use same TAG for each worker. If I use the same tags, I don't want to run for example W2 worker onTime and periodic at the same time, but because of the same TAG I can not filter which workers are the same.

Comment: You can cancel the old periodic work request and create a new one. Won't this work for you?

Comment: No I don't want to cancel, because some of my workers are sending data to the server.
If the first request have already been sent by the worker to the server, and an other instance of the same worker starts,
I can not cancel the first worker because its response is not processed yet, and the second worker will also send the request with the same object that I want to avoid.

Comment: Do you paas the data to be synced in the request itself?

Comment: No I don't, I have a Synchronization class, where I do the network calls, for exampe in the sendCertificates method I read the not sent rows from the database, and I do a Post request to the server. So basically inside the work I just call these methods.

Comment: Since you keep the data send of unsend posts in the database, then canceling requests shouldn't cause any problem. Are you worried that the two workers might run at the same time?

Comment: Yes I worry about it, because the first work can read the database, and if it doesn't get the response from the server pretty fast (for some reason), the other work instance can read the same data, and send to the server too. When the response arrives, the rows will be marked with  a bool, which means that it is synchronized. I will be updated my question with details soon, and you can see how it works.

Comment: Okay. So if I understood correctly till this point, what we want is that if user asks to sync data now, we need to check if that data is already being processed (sent to server and waiting for response). If it is, do nothing, otherwise sync it right now and after that keep doing it periodically. For the second case, I think we can just cancel the previous request and start a new one. The only thing remaining now is to detect if sync is in progress right now or not. Am I correct till here? Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: I think you're right. Especially the Invoice send worker starts automatically when the user create an invoice. In another fragment which is called Synchronization Fragment, the user can manually run this Invoice send worker, but in this case with different TAG. Currently I use a singleton mutex instance inside this worker, it provides that the sscond worker will wait before selectiong from Room while the first doesn't finish. When the first finihed the rows are updated and the second can't select again. I updated the question

Comment: Got it. What about this solution? Whenever the `SyncPricesWorker` starts, save a boolean `true` in sharedPrefs and remove it when the work it done. Then when user tries to manually run the worker, check for this sharedPref value, if it is there, don't do anything. Otherwise cancel the previous workRequest and start a new one. Will this work for you?

Comment: Thanks, it is the solution, but I applied a an another, instead of bool, I use a singleton mutex instance, and If two workers start almost at the same time, the second will wait. In my other workers which do just GET requests, I used the same TAG, so when the user wants to start more than 1, the first will be executed, while the others will canceled/not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WorkManager's TAG are properties of your WorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#tag_work), that you set using [`addTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#addTag(java.lang.String)) in the `WorkRequest.Builder`:

```java
val sendCertificatesWorker =
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
           SendCertificatesWorker::class.java, 900000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS
        )
                           .setConstraints(constraint)
                           .setInputData(data.build())
                           .setBackoffCriteria(
                               BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                               OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                               TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            )
                           .addTag(TAG) // <- ADDING A TAG
                           .build()
```

When you enqueue an unique work, [you're using a `uniqueName` to identify that *unique work*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#unique-work).

```kotlin
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(
        UNIQUE_NAME_NOW,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, sendCertificatesWorker
    )
```

Said that, WorkManager allows to set [chain of workers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work) for OneTimeWorkers, but not PeriodicWorkers.

It seems to me that the best option to achieve what you want is to add some controls at the start of W2 that checks the state of the oneTimeWorkers ([using unique TAGs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#observing)), and apply there the logic you need to achieve your desired outcome.

You need to pay some attention if you want to cover the case where W2 Periodic is already running, and you launch OneTime W1. In this case, or you [cancel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#cancelling) Periodic W2 from W1 (and [handle cancellation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#stop-worker) in W2) or you may end up with both W1 and W2 running at the same time.